# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 13 "Integrals", Prob. 23d: Prove Mean Value Theorem for Integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation

The following is a problem from chapter 13, "Integrals", from Spivak's Calculus

> 23. (a) Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $m \leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, then
>
> $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=(b-a)\mu$$
>
> for some number $\mu$ with $m \leq \mu \leq M$.
>
> (b) Prove that if $f$ is continuous on some $[a,b]$, then
>
> $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=(b-a)f(\xi)$$
>
> for some $\xi$ in $[a,b]$.
>
> (c) Show by an example that continuity is essential.
>
> (d) More generally, suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and
> that $g$ is integrable and nonnegative on $[a,b]$. Prove that
>
> $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=f(\xi)\int_a^b g(x)dx$$
>
> for some $\xi$ in $[a,b]$. This result is called the Mean Value
> Theorem for Integrals.

**My question is about how to solve $(d)$.**

Here is the solution from the solution manual for part $(d)$

> From the inequality $$mg(x) \leq f(x)g(x) \leq Mg(x)\tag{1}$$ we obtain
>
> $$m \int_a^b g(x)dx \leq \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx \leq M\int_a^b g(x)dx\tag{2}$$
>
> Consequently
>
> $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = \mu \int_a^b g(x)dx\tag{3}$$
>
> for some $\mu$ with $m \leq \mu \leq M$. This $\mu=f(\xi)$ for some
> $\xi$ in $[a,b]$.

**Let me try to go through the proof step-by-step in more words.**

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ by assumption, so it is bounded on $[a,b]$. Therefore, there exist $m$ and $M$ such that $m \leq f(x)\leq M$ and since $g(x)$ is nonnegative we can multiply by $g(x)$ and obtain $(1)$

If we integrate each function in the inequalities in $(1)$ we get the inequalities in $(2)$.

By $(a)$, since $f\cdot g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $(1)$, then

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=\mu(M-m)\int_a^b g(x)dx\tag{4}$$

for some $\mu \in [m\int_a^b g(x)dx, M\int_a^b g(x)dx]$

One more thing we know from $f$ being continuous on $[a,b]$ is that

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=(M-m)f(\xi)$$

for some $\xi \in [m,M]$.

How does one arrive at $(3)$?

Answer (score 2):

You have:$$m\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant M\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$So, if $\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$, you have $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$, in which case you can take *any* $\xi\in[a,b]$. Otherwise,$$m\leqslant\frac{\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx}{\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx}\leqslant M,$$and you take $\xi\in[a,b]$ such that$$f(\xi)=\frac{\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx}{\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\int_a^{b} g(x)dx\neq 0$ then we can define $\mu$ to be $\frac {\int_a^{b} f(x) g(x)dx}{ \int_a^{b} g(x)dx}$ and we get (3) from (2). In the case $\int_a^{b} g(x)dx= 0$ we get $\int_a^{b}f(x)g(x)dx=0$ also (from (2)) so we are at liberty to choose any $\mu$ between $m$ and $M$. Existence of $\xi$ such that $f(\xi)=\mu$ is by Intermediate Value Property of continuous functions.

Comment: Can you specify the exact steps that lead from your definition of $\mu$ to $(3)$ from $(2)$? $(3)$ is true automatically from your definition of $\mu$, but how do we know $\mu=f(\xi)$ for $\xi \in [a,b]$?

Comment: I am just dividing (2) by $\int_a^{b}g(x)dx$ which is positive (because it is given that $g \geq 0$). You can divide all the terms in an inequality by a positive number.  @evianpring

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to build on José Carlos Santos' answer by filling in some intermediate steps.

$f$ continuous on $[a,b]$

$\implies f$ bounded on $[a,b]$

$\implies \left [\exists m\ \exists M, \forall x, x \in [a,b] \implies m\leq f(x)\leq M \right ]$

$\implies mg(x)\leq f(x)g(x) \leq Mg(x), x \in [a,b]$

$\implies m \int_a^b g(x)dx \leq \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx \leq M\int_a^b g(x)dx\tag{1}$

**Case 1:** $\int_a^b g(x) \neq 0$

$\implies m \leq \frac{\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a^b g(x)} \leq M$

We're looking for some number $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=f(\xi)\int_a^bg(x)dx\tag{2}$$

That is some $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that

$$f(\xi)=\frac{\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a^b g(x)dx}$$

But we know that this $\xi$ must exist because of the Intermediate Value Theorem: $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ on $[a,b]$, therefore $f$ takes on every value between $m$ and $M$ in $[a,b]$, including $\frac{\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a^b g(x)dx}$ at some $\xi$.

**Case 2:** $\int_a^b g(x) = 0$

From $(1)$ we have $0\leq \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\leq 0$

$\implies \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=0$

Therefore, $(2)$ is true for any $\xi \in [a,b]$.